# How to determine unpartitioned space

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm using LVM on a system I set up a few years ago. At the time I left some unpartitioned space on the drive so I could create LVM snapshots.

I've now forgotten how much space I set aside.

How can I see how much is free?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the /usr/sbin/vgs command. It will list all the LVM volume groups, the total size of each one and the amount of free space.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to sagi's correct answer, as a more general way to help yourself with this, you can just type **`sudo lvm`** or run lvm as root to take you into a lvm console.

You can then type help to see all the lvm commands, this is a good way to help keep all these commands straight.

```
[kbrandt@machine: ~] sudo lvm                                                                                                                       
lvm> help
  Available lvm commands:
  Use 'lvm help <command>' for more information

  dumpconfig      Dump active configuration
  formats         List available metadata formats
  help            Display help for commands
  lvchange        Change the attributes of logical volume(s)
  lvconvert       Change logical volume layout
  lvcreate        Create a logical volume
  lvdisplay       Display information about a logical volume
  lvextend        Add space to a logical volume
  lvmchange       With the device mapper, this is obsolete and does nothing.
  lvmdiskscan     List devices that may be used as physical volumes
  lvmsadc         Collect activity data
  lvmsar          Create activity report
  lvreduce        Reduce the size of a logical volume
  lvremove        Remove logical volume(s) from the system
  lvrename        Rename a logical volume
  lvresize        Resize a logical volume
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`pvs` for example